# variable imageLen is not reseting after input[type file] change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, reset

I have this piece of code that are creating me problem....

```js
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".mylbl").click(function() {
        var imageslen, imagesSize, imagesName; //decleartion variale
        //Intiallize variables for prevent to upload many time images
        imageslen = imagesSize = imagesName = 0;
        $(".inputfile").click();
        $(".inputfile").change(function() {
          imageslen = 0;
          var uploadedImages = $(".inputfile")[0].files;
          imageslen = uploadedImages.length;
          imagesSize = [];
          imagesName = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < imageslen; i++) {
            imagesSize[i] = uploadedImages[i].size;
            imagesName[i] = uploadedImages[i].name;
            console.log(imagesSize[i]);
            console.log(imagesName[i]);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #f4f9c4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
form {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.mylbl {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff4500;
  line-height: 300%;
  border: 5px solid #C33100;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.inputfile {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #129EA4;
  border: none;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="myform" method="post" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="album" name="gallry[]" multiple class="inputfile" />
  <label for="imgrs" class="mylbl">Please Choose Images..</label>
  <input id="_d11re" type="button" name="addimagedata" value="Upload" class="_p25ed btn" />
</form>
```

**Before run this code open console of browser.. to check problem and upload more than 3 o four time images**

The problem is in js code that the variable imageslen isnt reset.. when first time i upload image, the code works correct and when i click second time on that labal("please choose image") for upload image image upload but two time.. 
here i show u small image of my google chrome..
[image]

Comment: You need o move change handler outside of click.

Comment: Yes its works but i have question. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everytime `mylbl` gets clicked, a new Change EventListener gets bound to `inputfile`.

```
$(".mylbl").click(function() {
    $(".inputfile").click();
    // move the rest of the function from HERE
}
// to HERE
```

if you have any problems more, make a jsFiddle or something else to show us your intermediate result.

Comment: doesnt not work .. please can u make snippet. Please please

Comment: once you clicked on `.mylbl` a new change event is bound to `.inputfile`. so the first time you click on `.mylbl` the function `$(".inputfile").change(function() {` executed once. the second time you click on `.mylbl` a second change EventListener gets bound. so the function `$(".inputfile").change(function() {` is executed two times only at the second click. the thrid time ... and so on and so on.

Comment: whats wrong with this array imageExt["jpeg","gif","bmp","png","jpg"]; ?

Comment: try `var imageExt = new Array("jpeg","g`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96418/discussion-between-phoenix-and-chris).

Comment: i understand where were problem this should me like this var imageExt = ["","","",""];